# Ubuntu 18 unmutes itself when a sound is played

Tags: 18.04, sound, 18.10, volume-control

I used to have this issue on 18.04 and I fixed it with help of some thread I found and now that I updated to 18.10 I'm having the issue again but I just can't find the old thread that helped me figure it out.

Basically as soon as any app outputs sound, my speakers unmute. I'm muting them using my keyboard key for that and I can see on the top bar that they are muted as the icon switches to the speaker with a line across. As soon as a sound comes in, the goes back to normal.

Any ideas?